# Controlling the column order when EclipseLink creates tables

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink with the "eclipselink.ddl-generation" property set to "create-tables".  The order of the columns in the created tables seems random.  I want the columns in a particular order - the order in which the fields appear in the Entity class definition.

Is there a way to tell EclipseLink to create the columns in the order in the Entity class definition or some other way to specify column order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything out of the box from EclipseLink to do this. Column order shouldn't matter in a properly normalized database.